# Simple: Need help refactoring this awkward looking method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring

How do I clean this up? It reads awkward and is way too long.

```
def report_total(feed_event, advisor)
  count = 0
  advisor.activity_feed_events.each do |lead|
    if lead == SignupFeedEvent
      count += 1
    else
      if lead.is_a?(feed_event) 
        if lead.event_date > (Time.now - 7.days)
          count += 1
        end
      end
    end
  end
  return count
end
```

Comment: This should be asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use:

```
def report_total(feed_event, advisor)
  advisor.activity_feed_events.count do |lead|
     lead == SignupFeedEvent ||
         (lead.is_a?(feed_event) && lead.event_date > (Time.now - 7.days))
  end
end
```

Does the same, way less code.

Answer (score 0):

Read a good book, for example Refactoring Ruby edition.

Good OO practices recommend not to check for class equality or is_a?, but rather check for the capabilities of the object, for example using respond_to?.

```
if lead.respond_to?(:event_date) ...
```